# Load class from Customized Plugin in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I created a plugin to load a class on clicking  new menu of eclipse. The Plugin works fine as runtime application but when i exported the plugins in the Plugin folder of eclipse,On launching IDE the new menu item appers but clicking on the new menu item it gives class not found exception and class not found by the Plugin qualifier.

I get the following exception

> ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2019-07-26 11:46:28.784 !MESSAGE Could not
>   create action delegate for id: botframeworkui.handlers.set.action1
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2019-07-26 11:46:28.784
>   !MESSAGE Plug-in botframeworkui.handlers was unable to load class
>   botframeworkui.handlers.SampleHandler. !STACK 0
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   botframeworkui.handlers.SampleHandler cannot be found by
>   botframeworkui.handlers_1.0.0.qualifier   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:934)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.lambda$0(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:218)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:451)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)

How to proceed forward?

Comment: All that stack trace tells us is that `botframeworkui.handlers.SampleHandler` can't be found. How are you accessing that class? The Eclipse plug-in system has very strict rules about accessing classes, some of these rules are not enforced when you test using 'Run Eclipse Application'

Comment: i am just accessing the class from the Plugin.xml  calling a class from one extension points. The class is present in package botframeworkui.handlers inside the Plugin folder ->Plugin ID.  Can i Know how can i load the class or the strict  rules to load the class of customized plugin in eclipse IDE?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are doing. [edit] your question and add more details.